# Can SQS trigger an event in AWS event bridge service?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, event-bus, aws-event-bridge

In my usecase I want to trigger an aws-lambda function if sqs payload message contain a specific attribute. For example following is an sqs payload

```
{
   "attribute1" : "test1",
   "attribure2" : "test2"
}
```

if sqs payload contains attribute named "attribure1" and its value is equal to "test1" , I want to trigger a lambda function named testLambda.

Can we create such rules with AWS event-bridge service(https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQS trigger do not work on data inside the message, rather on the submission of the message into the queue.

I would suggest a routing lambda sitting between your lambda with business logic and SQS. This routing Lambda will consume messages from SQS and route them to the required business logic lambdas. [Here](https://www.lucidchart.com/blog/cloud/5-reasons-why-sqs-lambda-triggers-are-a-big-deal) you can look at how triggers work and their use cases.

Comment: Is actually EventBridge notified on message submission? I believe that it is only getting informations about attribute changes or queue modifications?